# The arrow maze escape

Tags: code-golf, maze

**Question**

You have a 50 by 50 character array. Each cell has an arrow pointing in any one of four directions. No cell is empty. On entering a cell, you must exit it in the direction specified by the arrow. The arrow may also point in the same direction you came from, resulting in a dead end.

You may start from any cell on the outermost border of the maze and find a path that takes you in the maze, and causes you to exit at some other cell. Input will be given as an array containing <, >, ^ and v. Output will be a single digit (Boolean, integer or character, anything will do) as 0 (indicating that the task is impossible) or 1 (indicating that you have achieved the task).

**Example** (actual array will be bigger than this)

```
^ v < >
> < v <
v > v ^
```

Output will be

```
1
```

as you can enter from the < on the right, which will cause you to exit from the bottom v by the path "< v v"

**The task is to write the shortest possible code that will receive the maze as input, and determine where there exists a path in it as specified in the rules and output a single digit 0 or 1**

Outputing TRUE and FALSE instead of actual digits is also allowed.

Comment: It would be nice to have some actual test cases to work with

Comment: Is the input a one dimensional array or a two dimensional? And can you only enter on the right by a < or can you also enter by a ^ ?

Comment: @bobbel Input can be given as a 1 or a 2 dimensional array, whichever is required for a shorter code. Even arrows can be entered as 1 2 3 4 instead of < > ^ v if that can shorten the code. And yes,  you can enter via the ^ also.

Comment: @ LiamNoronha It's not that hard to randomly generate test cases.

Comment: You mention the possible output in several parts of the challenge, but I'm still not quite sure what exactly is permitted. My answer currently prints **1** if there exists a path and **0** if not. Could it also print **0** if there exists a path and **1** if not?

Comment: @Dennis No, it should print TRUE or 1 if there exists a path.

Comment: Oh, I may return the Boolean, integer or character **0**. Now I get it.

Comment: The likelihood that a random, 50 by 50, array will not have a solution is just about 0.  It would be better if you required that the solution have at least a certain number of steps or that the user specified the solution path.

Comment: Could I enter the bottom through a v?

Comment: @DanTheMan Nope.

Comment: This should have been called "An arrow escape"... Still pondering a solution.

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>89</s> 81 bytes

```
q~"><v^":A2/{f{\*}z}/sA[1W52-52]er:T,,{[52md]51f%0e=1=},:E{[2704{__T=+}*]\-E&},,g
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%22%3E%3Cv%5E%22%3AA2%2F%7Bf%7B%5C*%7Dz%7D%2FsA%5B1W52-52%5Der%3AT%2C%2C%7B%5B52md%5D51f%250e%3D1%3D%7D%2C%3AE%7B%5B2704%7B__T%3D%2B%7D*%5D%5C-E%26%7D%2C%2Cg&input=%5B%22%3E%3C%3Evv%5E%3C%3C%5Evvvv%3Ev%3C%3E%5E%3C%3E%3E%3Cvv%5E%3E%5E%3C%5E%3E%3E%3Ev%3E%5Evv%3E%3C%5Ev%3Ev%3E%3E%5Ev%5Ev%5E%22%0A%20%22%3E%3Cv%3Ev%3E%3E%3E%3Cv%5E%5Ev%5E%3E%3E%3C%5E%3E%3C%3Evv%3C%3E%5E%3C%3C%3Cv%5E%5E%3E%3E%5Ev%3Ev%5E%3E%3E%3E%5E%3E%3E%3E%5E%3E%3C%3C%22%0A%20%22%5Ev%5E%5E%3E%5E%5E%3Evv%5E%5E%5E%3Evv%3E%5E%5E%5E%3C%5E%5E%3E%3E%5E%5E%3Cv%5Ev%3E%3C%5E%3E%5Evv%3C%3C%3C%3E%5E%3E%5E%5Ev%3E%3Ev%22%0A%20%22v%3E%5Ev%3C%3E%3C%3E%3C%3E%3C%3E%3C%5E%3E%3C%3Ev%3E%3Ev%3C%3E%3Ev%3Ev%3E%3E%3C%5E%5E%5E%3C%3E%3Evv%3E%3C%5E%3C%3E%3E%3E%3Cv%3C%3C%5E%22%0A%20%22vv%3C%3Cv%3C%5E%3C%3Cvv%5E%3E%3E%5E%3C%3C%3E%5Evvvv%5E%5E%3E%5Evv%3C%3E%5E%3C%5E%3C%3E%5E%3C%3E%3Ev%5E%5E%3E%5E%5E%3E%3C%5Ev%22%0A%20%22v%5E%5E%3C%5E%3E%3C%3Cvv%3Cv%3Ev%5E%3E%3E%3C%3E%3E%3C%3E%3Evv%3C%5E%5E%5E%3C%5E%3Evv%5E%3E%3E%3E%3C%5E%5E%3E%5E%3C%3Cv%5E%5E%3Cv%22%0A%20%22v%3Cvv%3E%3E%5Ev%3Ev%5Ev%3E%5E%5E%5Evv%3Cv%3E%3E%5Evvv%3C%3E%3E%3C%3E%3C%3Cv%5E%5E%5E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3C%5E%5E%5Ev%5E%5E%3C%5E%22%0A%20%22%5Ev%3C%5E%3C%5E%5E%3C%3C%3E%3C%3E%3Cvvvvv%5E%3C%3C%3Cv%3C%3Ev%5E%5E%5E%5E%5E%3Evv%3C%3Ev%3E%5Ev%3E%3Cv%5E%3E%5Ev%5E%3Cv%22%0A%20%22%3C%3E%5Ev%3C%5E%3Cvvv%5E%3E%5E%3Cv%5E%3C%3C%3C%3E%5E%5Ev%5E%5E%3Ev%3Ev%5E%3E%3Evvv%3E%3E%5E%3Cv%5E%3Cv%3E%5E%5Evv%3E%5E%22%0A%20%22%5E%5Evv%3C%3Ev%3C%3Cvv%3C%3C%3Ev%5E%5Ev%3Cvvv%5E%3E%3Cvv%3C%3C%3Evvv%3C%3E%3Ev%3Cv%3C%3E%3E%3E%5E%3C%5E%5E%5E%3E%3E%22%0A%20%22%3C%3C%3Cv%3C%3C%3Evvv%5E%3C%3C%3E%3Cv%5E%5E%3C%5E%5Evv%3Cvvv%5E%3C%3Evv%3Ev%5Ev%3Cv%3C%3E%3C%3E%5E%5E%5E%3E%3E%3E%3Ev%22%0A%20%22v%3Ev%3E%5E%3E%5E%5Ev%5E%3C%3C%3C%5E%3E%3Ev%3Ev%5E%3C%5E%3Ev%5E%3E%3C%5Ev%5E%3E%3C%3C%5Evv%5E%3C%5E%5Ev%5E%5E%5E%5E%3Cv%3E%5E%3C%22%0A%20%22%3Cv%5E%3C%3Ev%3Cv%3E%5E%3C%3C%5E%3E%5E%3C%5E%5Ev%5E%3E%3Cv%3E%3C%3E%3E%5E%3C%3C%3C%5Ev%3E%5Ev%3E%5E%3C%5E%5E%3Ev%5E%3C%5E%3Cv%5E%3C%22%0A%20%22v%3C%3E%5Ev%5E%3C%3E%3C%3C%3E%5E%3C%3E%3C%3E%3E%3Ev%5E%3C%3Ev%3E%5E%3C%5Ev%3C%3Cvv%5E%3E%3E%3E%3C%3C%3E%3Ev%3E%5E%3E%3C%3E%5E%3Evv%22%0A%20%22v%5E%5E%3Cv%3C%3C%3Ev%3E%3C%5E%3C%3Ev%5E%3Cv%5E%3E%3E%5E%5E%3E%3C%3C%5E%3E%3C%5E%3C%3Cv%5Ev%3E%5E%5E%5E%5E%3E%3Ev%5E%5E%5E%3Ev%3Ev%22%0A%20%22vv%5E%5Ev%5E%5E%5E%3C%3E%5E%5E%5E%3C%3C%3E%3E%3Cv%5E%3E%3E%5Evvv%5E%5E%3Ev%3Evv%3E%3C%3E%5E%3C%3E%3C%3E%3Cv%3E%5Ev%3E%3E%3E%5E%22%0A%20%22%3E%5E%5Ev%3C%3E%3E%3E%5Ev%3E%3Evv%3E%5E%5E%3E%3E%3Cv%3C%3E%3C%3C%3C%5E%3C%3E%3C%3E%5E%3Cv%3Ev%3C%5Ev%3Cv%3Ev%3E%5Ev%5E%3Ev%3C%22%0A%20%22%3E%3E%3E%3Cv%3E%5E%3C%5Evvv%3E%5E%3Cvv%5E%3E%5E%5E%3E%3Evv%3E%3Ev%5Ev%3Cvv%3Cv%5Evvv%3C%3E%5E%3C%3E%3C%3E%3E%3C%3E%5E%22%0A%20%22%3E%5E%3Evv%5E%3Cv%5E%5E%3E%3C%3E%3C%3Cvv%5E%5E%3E%3Ev%3C%5E%5Ev%5E%3C%5E%3C%3C%5Ev%3Ev%3C%3C%5E%3C%3E%3C%3Evv%3E%5Ev%3Cv%3C%22%0A%20%22v%3C%3C%3E%5E%3C%3C%5Ev%5E%3C%5E%5Ev%5E%3E%3E%3C%3C%5E%3E%3E%3E%5E%3E%3E%3Cv%3C%3Cv%3C%3Cvv%3C%3C%3E%5Evv%5Ev%3Ev%3E%5E%5E%3Ev%22%0A%20%22%3C%3E%5Ev%3E%3C%5E%5E%3C%5Ev%5E%3Ev%3Ev%3Cv%3C%3C%3E%3E%5E%3Ev%5E%5E%3Cv%5E%3C%5E%5E%3Cv%5E%3E%5Ev%5E%3Cvvvv%5E%3C%5Evv%22%0A%20%22%3E%3E%3Cv%5E%3C%5E%3Cv%3E%3E%3Cvv%3C%3E%5E%3C%3C%3C%3E%3C%5E%3C%3C%5Evv%3E%3C%5Ev%3E%3Ev%3C%3E%5E%3E%5E%3C%3C%5E%3Cv%3Evv%3Ev%22%0A%20%22%5Evv%3E%3C%3Evv%3Ev%3E%3E%3E%3C%5E%5Ev%3E%3E%3E%5E%3Cv%3E%3Cv%3Cv%3E%5E%3C%3Ev%5Evvv%5Ev%3E%5E%3E%3C%5E%3Evvv%3Ev%22%0A%20%22%3C%5Ev%3Cv%5E%5E%3E%3E%3C%5Ev%3C%3C%3E%3C%5Evv%5E%5Evv%3C%5Ev%3E%5E%3E%5E%3E%3C%3Ev%3Cv%3Cv%3C%3C%5E%3Cv%5E%5E%5Ev%3Cv%3C%22%0A%20%22%3Cvv%5E%5E%5E%5E%3C%5E%3E%5E%3C%3E%3C%3E%3C%3C%3Cvv%3E%3C%3C%5Ev%5Ev%3E%3C%3E%3Cv%3Ev%3C%3E%5E%3E%3C%3E%3E%3E%5E%5E%3C%3Evv%3Ev%22%0A%20%22v%3Evv%3C%3E%5Ev%3C%5E%3E%3C%3Evv%3E%3C%3E%5E%3Ev%3C%5E%3E%3E%5E%3C%3E%3Ev%3C%3Cvv%5Ev%5E%3E%3E%3E%5E%5Ev%5E%5E%3C%3E%5Ev%5E%22%0A%20%22%5E%3E%5E%5Ev%3C%3E%5Evv%5E%3E%3E%3Cv%3C%3C%5Ev%3Evvv%3E%5E%5E%3C%3Cv%3E%5E%3Ev%3E%3Ev%3C%3E%3Ev%5E%3Ev%3E%5Ev%3E%3Cv%3E%22%0A%20%22v%3C%3E%3E%3E%5E%3C%3E%3C%5E%3C%3Ev%5E%3C%3C%3C%3C%5E%3C%3Cvv%3Evv%5Ev%3C%5E%3Cv%3C%5E%3Cv%3Ev%5E%5E%3C%3E%5Ev%3E%3E%3C%3E%5E%3E%22%0A%20%22%3C%3Cv%3Ev%3E%5E%3E%3C%5E%5E%3E%3C%3Evvvvv%3E%3Ev%3C%3E%5E%3E%5E%3C%3C%5Evv%5E%3C%3C%5Ev%3C%3C%3E%3E%3Cv%5E%5E%3E%5E%3Ev%3E%22%0A%20%22vvv%3Evvvv%3E%3E%3C%3Cv%3Ev%3Evv%5E%5E%3C%5E%5E%3C%3E%3C%5E%5E%3C%3Cv%3E%3Cv%3Cv%3C%5E%5E%3Ev%3C%5E%3C%3C%5Evvvv%22%0A%20%22v%3C%3Evv%3C%3E%3Ev%5E%5E%3C%3E%3Ev%5E%3Ev%5E%5Ev%3Ev%3E%3Evv%5E%3Cv%3E%3Ev%5E%3C%3E%3E%5E%3C%3E%3Cv%3E%5E%3Cv%5E%3C%5Ev%22%0A%20%22%3E%3E%5E%3C%5E%3E%3E%5E%3E%3E%3Ev%5E%3E%3E%5E%5E%3E%3C%5E%5E%3C%3C%3E%5E%5E%3E%3E%3C%5Ev%5E%3E%3Evvv%3E%5E%3E%3E%3C%3E%3C%5E%3Cvv%5Ev%22%0A%20%22%5Ev%5E%3Cvvv%3E%3C%5Ev%3E%3C%3E%3E%3Ev%5E%3C%3E%3E%3C%3E%5E%3E%3C%3C%3E%3E%5E%3Ev%5Ev%3C%5E%5E%5Ev%3C%3E%3Ev%3Evvv%3E%3E%3E%22%0A%20%22%3C%3C%3E%3E%3Cv%3E%3E%3Cv%3E%5E%5E%5E%3E%5Ev%3E%3Evv%3Ev%5Ev%5E%3C%3C%3E%3C%3Cv%3Cvv%3Cv%3Cv%5E%3C%3C%5Evv%3Ev%3Cv%5E%22%0A%20%22%5Ev%3E%3E%3C%5Ev%3Cv%3Cv%3C%3Ev%3C%3E%3E%5Ev%3C%3E%3E%5E%3C%3E%5E%3E%3C%3C%5E%3E%5E%5E%3E%3E%3C%3Cv%5E%3C%5E%3C%3C%5E%3E%3E%5E%3E%5Ev%22%0A%20%22%5E%3C%5E%3C%5E%5Ev%5Ev%3C%3E%3C%3Cv%5E%3C%3C%3E%3Ev%3E%3C%3Ev%5E%5Ev%3E%3C%5E%5E%3Ev%3E%5Ev%3Ev%3Ev%5Ev%3C%3C%3C%3E%5E%5E%5E%3C%22%0A%20%22%3E%5E%3C%3C%5E%5E%5Evv%5Ev%3Ev%3C%5E%5E%5Evv%5E%5E%3Ev%3E%3E%5E%3Ev%3C%3E%3C%3Ev%3C%3C%3E%3E%3E%3Cv%3E%5E%3E%3E%3C%5E%3C%3C%3E%5E%22%0A%20%22%5E%3C%5Ev%3E%3Cv%3Ev%3C%3C%3Ev%3C%5E%5E%3E%3Cvv%5E%5Evv%5E%5E%3Ev%5E%3C%3Ev%5E%3C%3E%3E%3C%3C%3C%5E%3Ev%3E%3E%3E%3C%3Cv%3C%5E%22%0A%20%22v%3E%3Cv%3Cv%3C%3E%5E%3E%3E%3C%3C%5E%3C%5E%3E%3C%3C%5E%5E%3Ev%3E%5Ev%3C%3Ev%3C%3Cv%5E%5E%3E%5Ev%5E%5Ev%3Cv%3E%3E%3E%3C%3E%3C%5Ev%22%0A%20%22%3E%5E%3C%5Ev%3E%5Ev%3E%3C%3E%3C%5E%3C%5E%3E%3E%3C%5Ev%3E%3C%3Cv%5Evv%3Cvvv%3E%3C%5E%3E%5E%3E%3C%5E%3C%3E%3E%5E%5E%5E%5Ev%3E%5Ev%22%0A%20%22%3Cv%5E%3E%5Evvv%3C%5E%3C%3Cv%5Ev%3C%3C%5E%5E%3Ev%3Ev%3C%5Evv%3C%3C%3E%3E%5E%3C%3Ev%5E%5E%5E%5E%3Ev%3Ev%5E%5E%3Ev%5E%3E%3C%22%0A%20%22v%5E%3E%3E%5E%3C%5Ev%3E%5E%3E%5E%5E%3Ev%3E%3Ev%3E%5E%5Ev%3Ev%3Ev%3Cv%3C%3C%5Ev%5E%3C%3E%5E%5E%3C%5E%3E%3E%3Cv%3E%5E%3C%3C%5E%5Ev%22%0A%20%22v%5E%5E%3C%5E%5E%3C%5Ev%5E%5E%3C%3E%3C%3E%3Ev%3E%5E%3E%3Cv%3Ev%3C%3E%3Ev%3C%5E%3C%3Ev%3E%5E%3E%5E%3E%5E%3C%5E%3Cv%3E%5Ev%3E%3C%3E%5E%22%0A%20%22%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3C%3E%3C%3C%5Ev%3C%5Ev%5E%3Evv%3Ev%3E%3C%3Cv%3C%3C%3E%3Ev%3Ev%3Cv%3E%3Evv%5E%5E%3C%3C%3E%3Ev%5E%5Evvvv%22%0A%20%22%3E%5Ev%3C%3C%5E%3Cvv%5E%5E%3C%5Ev%3E%3C%3C%5E%3C%5E%5E%5E%5E%3E%3E%3E%3C%3C%3C%3Cv%5E%3Ev%3E%5Ev%5E%3Evv%3E%3Evv%3C%3Cv%5E%3C%22%0A%20%22%3E%5Ev%5E%3C%3C%3Cv%5E%3E%5Ev%3Cv%3Cv%3E%3Cv%3C%3C%3E%5E%3C%3C%3E%3Ev%3E%5E%3E%3C%3Cv%5Ev%5E%3C%3E%3Ev%3E%5E%3Ev%3Cvv%5E%3C%22%0A%20%22v%3E%5E%3E%5Ev%3Cv%3E%3C%3Ev%3Evv%3E%3E%3E%3E%5E%3C%3E%5E%5E%3Ev%3C%3E%3C%3E%5E%3E%5E%3C%5Ev%3C%5Ev%5E%5E%3C%3Ev%3E%3C%3Ev%5E%3C%22%0A%20%22%3Cv%5E%3E%3Ev%3Ev%3C%3C%3E%3C%5E%5E%3Cv%3E%3C%3E%5E%3E%5E%3E%3E%3Ev%3C%3C%3E%3E%5E%3C%3E%3E%3C%3E%3E%3Cv%3E%3E%3E%5Ev%3E%3Cv%3Ev%3E%22%0A%20%22vv%5Ev%3Ev%3Evv%5E%5E%3E%5E%3C%5E%3E%5E%5Ev%5Ev%3C%5E%5Evv%3Cv%5Evv%3E%3Cv%3C%3Ev%5E%3C%3C%5Ev%3E%5Ev%3C%3Ev%5E%5E%22%0A%20%22%3Cv%5Evv%3C%3C%5Evv%5E%5E%5Ev%5E%3C%5E%5E%3Ev%3C%5E%5E%5E%5Ev%3E%3E%3E%3C%3E%5E%3C%5E%5E%3Evv%3C%3E%3C%5E%5E%3E%3C%3E%3C%5Evv%22%5D).

#### How it works

```
q~        e# Read and evaluate all input. This pushes an array of strings.
"><v^":A  e# Push that string and save it in A.
2/        e# Split it into ["><" "v^"].
{         e# For each chunk:
  f{      e#   For each input string, push the string and the chunk; then:
    \*    e#     Join the chunk, using the string as separator.
  }       e#
  z       e#   Transpose rows and columns.
}/        e#
s         e# Flatten the resulting array of strings.
A         e# Push "><v^".
[1W52-52] e# Push [1 -1 52 -52].
er        e# Perform transliteration.
:T        e# Save the result in T.
,,        e# Push [0 ... 2703].
{         e# Filter; for each integer I in [0 ... 2703]:
  [52md]  e#   Push [I/52 I%52].
  51f%    e#   Take both integers modulo 51 to map 51 to 0.
  0e=     e#   Count the number of resulting zeroes.
  1=      e#   Check if the count is 1.
},        e# If it is, keep I.
:E        e# Save the filtered array in E.
{         e# For each integer I in E:
  [2704{  e#   Do 2704 times:
    __    e#     Push two copies of the integer on the stack.
    T=    e#     Select the corresponding element from T.
    +     e#     Add it to the first copy.
  }*]     e#   Collect all results in an array.
  \-      e#   Remove I from that array.
  E&      e#   Intersect with E.
},        e# If the intersection is non-empty, keep the integer.
,g        e# Push the sign of the length of the filtered array.
```